# How to control Google Clound Message from Web-service in php

Tags: php, android, web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I have a scenario as below figure. In which, I want to send a request from my phone to web-service (created by php). When the message is received, the web service will sent that message to Google clound Message. The GCM will respond a notification to my phone. 
 [image]

Hence, I have a question is how can i create a web-service to send a request to GMS when it receive a request from my phone. Note that my goal is that recived a push message from GCM. Thank you so much. If you have any source code reference for that task, please let me know

Comment: There seems no use of GCM in your case. If you client contact to server then there is no meaning of replying to client via GCM. It will be useful when if you want to sent something to client then you can say to GCM like there is something to a particular device, please inform that device. Now your device will be notified by GCM and then your device can goto server to take update.

Comment: Actually, the my message that sent to web service will be added some information before sent it to GCM. Hence, web-service looks like a processing my data. For example, my phone will send phone ID, the web service will map it to personal name and send it GCM. The GCM will send it to my phone again. The benifit of GCM is that GCM can create a notification that will be useful for my task.

Comment: GCM can not create a notification. Please read again about GCM, and if your only use is to show notification then you can also show notification when you get data from server direct.

Comment: I means a Push Notifications. Is it possible if I only use web service?

Comment: The scenario you have described is most definitely not push. The client is connecting to the server. So why don't you just send the reply down the same pipeline???

Comment: The processing data must be implemented in my web service. Mean while, the push message is sent from GCM. Hence, I need both web service and GCM in my scenario. And assumtion that my phone is turned off, the GCM's nessage will be displayed when my phone is turned on

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that step 2 occurs some time after, step 1 and thus cannot be fulfilled by a direct HTTP response.

Typical GCM implementation would handle your scenario. Have a look at the [quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) to get going.

Also you can send a [notification message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) with GCM.